# Dashboard prompt issue in OBIEE 11g

Tags: obiee

OBI - Analysis
I created 2 column prompt,

1.mid_head
 2.sub_head

when I tried pulling out data from mid_head that's working fine,but when tried the same with sub_head, it's showing me the following error

> Failed to load(Invalid JSON payload:

what can be done to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. It might be caused due to special characters in the 'sub_head' column. If you have support.oracle.com access then check this document. Doc ID 2178233.1